# Buying air tickets for another person in another country

Tags: air-travel, tickets

I will be travelling back to my home country from the USA during the month of December. As I couldn't afford to buy a ticket on my own, my mother bought the air ticket for me, online, through one of my home country's travel site. Now is this valid? Can I travel with those air tickets that were purchased from an overseas travel site, from the USA to my home country? The ticket bears my name correctly as it appears in my passport. Please advice.

P.S. - On checking the PNR that was generated for that journey, it shows that the ticket is confirmed in my name.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should be no problem. I have done this many times for others and family members frequently do this for one another for various reasons.

There are apparently some odd regions where the bearer of the ticket is asked to show the credit card used to purchase the ticket but I have never experienced this in decades of travel across 56 countries and so I am only mentioning this because another question on this site asked about such a case.

In any case this happens in tons of situations such as buying tickets for a group, buying tickets from a corporate office for employees, etc. It is hard to think of any reason why a genuine ticket would not be considered valid.

Comment: While Itai has traveled without issue, I have been asked to show the card and on one occasion had to buy a new ticket. **So this issue does occur.** Rather than being lackadaisical about it as Itai suggests, call the airline and ask their policy.